# YahooAPI JSON callback converts first character to _underscore

Tags: json, yahoo-api

I have a YahooAPI call as under:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url=%22https://xgcwallet.org/ex/GetWebTransactions/18ESQ4HuHJPDc18iRUQRXpscV2oh8bn1fe%22&format=json&callback=
```

which gives me the result:

```
{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2015-08-17T19:32:10Z","lang":"en-us","results":{
 "json":{"_5c5731a04b825c46e9642bc12685db8dc7c4c367e022ac6ba95ee166024873e":{
  "hash":"75c5731a04b825c46e9642bc12685db8dc7c4c367e022ac6ba95ee166024873e","ver":"1","in":{
   "prev_out":{
     "hash":"27e841f82d44f82bdc1a2e6de162f3b133aa9db1372ce02f86f057a46555e35e","n":"0"},
   "address":"18ESQ4HuHJPDc18iRUQRXpscV2oh8bn1fe"},
  "out":[
    {"value":"1",
     "n":"0",
     "scriptPubKey":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 9b92ebd4706328bc1e66a5d60eade8e2e688b04c OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
     "address":"1FBbjzuX3xiWZZgMmApdS7xZsGYy8RFZP9"
    },{
   "value":"8.99",
   "n":"1",
   "scriptPubKey":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 4f537d20b30cd892c48ce574a746adbc757efcdd OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
   "address":"18ESQ4HuHJPDc18iRUQRXpscV2oh8bn1fe"
 }],
"time":"2015-08-17 19:16:00",
  "block":"00000000000001291109e7c399cc3b229a65ebe8d5caa7d9da70712dbe9fa194",
  "blocknumber":"75424"
  },"a6701ff7a5cfd97ff55730326ec281e0ad842b457b9c66b9c9e9cba9c8b0d724":{"hash":"a6701ff7a5cfd97ff55730326ec281e0ad842b457b9c66b9c9e9cba9c8b0d724","ver":"1","in":{"prev_out":{"hash":"275e9532c3a820fa790d553ff9fe21bf12f1dceacf2f751a8e6f6fa2b10fbec3","n":"2"},"address":"1JKZ7QPscvdjwvkcAeN9aBxw1Jk3zvuz9k"},"out":{"value":"0.9796","n":"0","scriptPubKey":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 150994b6688043aa707f35db752d34faed831f63 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG","address":"12vEfirXhAkgJWMq14aBsHpJD39FGztb2i"},"time":"2015-08-17 19:07:27","block":"0000000000000447278208af6264a8e86c19d57fed47d85a3a01c4b7030e2643","blocknumber":"75423"}}}}}
```

If I execute the URL directly from the browser as:

https://xgcwallet.org/ex/GetWebTransactions/18ESQ4HuHJPDc18iRUQRXpscV2oh8bn1fe

It will give me the result as under:

```
{"75c5731a04b825c46e9642bc12685db8dc7c4c367e022ac6ba95ee166024873e":{
 "hash":"75c5731a04b825c46e9642bc12685db8dc7c4c367e022ac6ba95ee166024873e","ver":1,"in":[{"prev_out":{"hash":"27e841f82d44f82bdc1a2e6de162f3b133aa9db1372ce02f86f057a46555e35e","n":0},"address":"18ESQ4HuHJPDc18iRUQRXpscV2oh8bn1fe"}],"out":[{"value":"1","n":0,"scriptPubKey":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 9b92ebd4706328bc1e66a5d60eade8e2e688b04c OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG","address":"1FBbjzuX3xiWZZgMmApdS7xZsGYy8RFZP9"},{"value":"8.99","n":1,"scriptPubKey":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 4f537d20b30cd892c48ce574a746adbc757efcdd OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG","address":"18ESQ4HuHJPDc18iRUQRXpscV2oh8bn1fe"}],"time":"2015-08-17 19:16:00","block":"00000000000001291109e7c399cc3b229a65ebe8d5caa7d9da70712dbe9fa194","blocknumber":75424},"a6701ff7a5cfd97ff55730326ec281e0ad842b457b9c66b9c9e9cba9c8b0d724":{"hash":"a6701ff7a5cfd97ff55730326ec281e0ad842b457b9c66b9c9e9cba9c8b0d724","ver":1,"in":[{"prev_out":{"hash":"275e9532c3a820fa790d553ff9fe21bf12f1dceacf2f751a8e6f6fa2b10fbec3","n":2},"address":"1JKZ7QPscvdjwvkcAeN9aBxw1Jk3zvuz9k"}],"out":[{"value":"0.9796","n":0,"scriptPubKey":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 150994b6688043aa707f35db752d34faed831f63 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG","address":"12vEfirXhAkgJWMq14aBsHpJD39FGztb2i"}],"time":"2015-08-17 19:07:27","block":"0000000000000447278208af6264a8e86c19d57fed47d85a3a01c4b7030e2643","blocknumber":75423}}
```

If you will notice Yahoo has converted the first char to '**_**' underscore, while returning the result.

In this example {"**_**5c5731a04b825c...........

Why does it do so in this query?

Can anyone explain, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first character of the returned JSON should never be a number. If it is a number it is not a valid JSON, so it is converted to "_". In my case the first char was "7" and was converted to "_".

Please correct the JSON. Yahoo API will work perfect.